# How to add indicator variable columns and add names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with a data frame in which I have created binary variables that indicate whether a certain individual was present in the "Players" column.

```
Layer       Grade       Players                    Var 2             NYAL 08   NYAL 27        
Top           A         NYAL 08; NYAL 27; NYAL 80  NYAL 08; MAAC 48    1       1      ...
Bottom        D         MAAC 27; MAAC 45; MAAC 65  NYAL 27             0       0      ...    
Middle        B         NYAL 08; MAAC 48; NYAL 66  MAAC 48;MAAC 22     0       0      ...       
...
```

I would like to add binary variables to the same data set that simple indicate if an individual is present in Var 2. However, since most all of the individuals are the same, I would like to add the letter "B" to the column names to separate those new indicator columns from the existing ones. How might it be possible to do this?

```
Layer       Grade       Players             Var 2            NYAL 08 NYAL 27 NYAL 08B NYAL 27B    
Top           A         NYAL 08; NYAL 27   NYAL 08; MAAC 48    1       1      1       0
Bottom        D         MAAC 27; MAAC 45   NYAL 27             0       0      0       1
Middle        B         NYAL 08; MAAC 48   NYAL 27; MAAC 22    0       0      0       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example showed

```
library(qdapTools)
#players_out <- mtabulate(strsplit(df1$Players, ";\\s+"))
var2_out <- mtabulate(strsplit(df1$Var2, ";\\s+"))
nm1 <- intersect(names(players_out), names(df1)[-(1:4)])
df1[paste0(nm1, "B")] <- var2_out[nm1]
```

-output

```
df1
#    Layer Grade          Players             Var2 NYAL 08 NYAL 27 NYAL 08B NYAL 27B
#1    Top     A NYAL 08; NYAL 27 NYAL 08; MAAC 48       1       1        1        0
#2 Bottom     D MAAC 27; MAAC 45          NYAL 27       0       0        0        1
#3 Middle     B NYAL 08; MAAC 48 NYAL 27; MAAC 22       0       0        0        1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Layer = c("Top", "Bottom", "Middle"), Grade = c("A", 
"D", "B"), Players = c("NYAL 08; NYAL 27", "MAAC 27; MAAC 45", 
"NYAL 08; MAAC 48"), Var2 = c("NYAL 08; MAAC 48", "NYAL 27", 
"NYAL 27; MAAC 22"), `NYAL 08` = c(1L, 0L, 0L), `NYAL 27` = c(1L, 
0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
u <- t(sapply(strsplit(df$Var2,";\\s+"),function(v) +sapply(tail(names(df),2),`%in%`, v)))
df <- cbind(df,`colnames<-`(u,paste0(colnames(u),"B")))
```

which gives

```
   Layer Grade          Players             Var2 NYAL 08 NYAL 27 NYAL 08B
1    Top     A NYAL 08; NYAL 27 NYAL 08; MAAC 48       1       1        1
2 Bottom     D MAAC 27; MAAC 45          NYAL 27       0       0        0
3 Middle     B NYAL 08; MAAC 48 NYAL 27; MAAC 22       0       0        0
  NYAL 27B
1        0
2        1
3        1
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Layer = c("Top", "Bottom", "Middle"), Grade = c("A", 
"D", "B"), Players = c("NYAL 08; NYAL 27", "MAAC 27; MAAC 45",
"NYAL 08; MAAC 48"), Var2 = c("NYAL 08; MAAC 48", "NYAL 27",
"NYAL 27; MAAC 22"), `NYAL 08` = c(1L, 0L, 0L), `NYAL 27` = c(1L,
0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```